# Attached objects to public Text removed on play mode (Unity)

Tags: unity, c#

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see when I play the game the 'touch anywhere to start' object goes away. How do I fix this?

*I have added all the relevant code*

Comment: For anyone wondering, I have added 'textManager()' to Update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `starttext` field is being set to null because *you told Unity that's what you wanted it to do.*

1. At edit time, you assigned a `Text` instance to the public `starttext` variable in the inspector for your `StartSceneManager` component.
2. You run the game, and `StartSceneManager.Start()` is called:

   `void Start() { starttext = GetComponent<Text>(); }`
3. This method overwrites `starttext` with the return value of `GetComponent<Text>()`, discarding whatever you put into that variable at edit time.
4. `GetComponent<Text>()` looks for a `Text` component *attached to the same GameObject* as the component it's running in (`StartSceneManager`). Since the StartSceneManager object has no `Text` component attached, the return value is `null`.

The fix is, if you want to assign the `Text` component to use at edit time in the Inspector, don't overwrite it in `Start()`.